# why Button SubView will not go to the back in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subview, addsubview

I have a view class with xib file so I want to use this view at the background of the button so I used subview but the problem is that the subview of the button will be inFront of the button so I can't click button any more I used UI Debugging mode and I realized that the button is at the back of the view so I used send to back in my codes But still the view is inFront of the Button !

```
 let adsView = videoAdsView()
func adsOutlet() {
    self.adsView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
    self.showAdsOutlet.addSubview(adsView)
    self.showAdsOutlet.sendSubview(toBack: self.adsView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    adsOutlet()
}
```

Comment: Is `showAdsOutlet` variable your button, and `adsView` is background view you want in the back of your button?

Comment: yes showAdsOutlet is my Button and adsView is my View that should be in the back of the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put following code at the end of adsOutlet method:

```
self.adsView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add your button as a subview of your background view then you can just do that, and your button will be in front of the background:

```swift
self.backgroundView.addSubview(adsButton)
```

If you don't want `adsButton` as a subview of the `backgroundView` but you want to make sure it's presented in front of the `backgroundView` then assuming that both are subview's of the parent `view` do this:

```
self.view.sendSubview(toFront:adsButton)
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that you're having an issue setting the button in front of the background view, but the real issue was that you were unable to interact with it.

Comment: no problem But the answer of mohammad_Z74 solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

Make the button `background color` clear. 
Then write this code:

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: showAdsOutlet)
```

It may helps to you. Thank you